# How would you pick a distribution with N atoms to approximate, in some way, the Normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question is not mathematically precise and some of you will probably vote to close it, but nevertheless I feel like there must be precise answer.

Consider Normal distribution $N(0,1)$

If you were told to describe this distribution with only one point in $R$, what point would you choose? For me obvious answer is $0$, mean of distribution, point with highest density.

But, if you were told to describe this distribution with two points in $R$, what points would you choose? I don't know , looking at normal density my intuition tells me that I would choose something like $(-0.5,0.5)$

Is there mathematically precise definition of what I say as "describe distribution"?

How can I choose $N$ points  from Normal in $R^d (\mu, \Sigma)$?

Comment: Maybe a better question would be, "how would you pick a distribution with $N$ atoms to approximate, in some way, the Normal distribution?"

Answer (score 1):

I would propose describing the standard normal with $d$ points by taking the points $F^{-1}(\frac{k}{d+1})$ for $1\leq k\leq d$. This gives you, in some sense, $d$ "evenly" distributed points acoording to the normal distribution. That is, the probability between two adjacent points is constant.

Comment: Good idea! I am not sure how to generalize this to multivariate case

Answer (score 0):

$\{-1,1\}$ would have mean $0$ and variance $1$

Comment: Thanks. How can I approach the same question with $N$ points to choose from Normal in $R^d (\mu, \Sigma)$?

Comment: I suspect you need $N \gg d$; if $N$ is big enough perhaps you could try simulation

Comment: Unfortunately $N$ is small.